# Looking for a word that describes a polished résumé

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a word you would use to describe a résumé that is "shiny" or "polished." For instance, if somebody went to say Stanford and then worked at NASA, their résumé would have a lot more *x* than a résumé with no-name schools and employers.

I'm having a hard time remembering what word it is I'm looking for; it's not esteem or respectability, but I do believe it starts with a *p-* (though when not remembering the word, such beliefs are admittedly often wrong). I'm pretty sure it's a somewhat rare word, if that is any help.

Some other words that are somewhat in the general area of what I'm looking for, but not it: *acclaim, accomplished, illustrious, sparkle, repute, prestige* (though that one feels closest).

Comment: I'd advise against using "pedigree" unless you want to be a bit snarky.  / Would you please conform to the norms of the site and give one or two sample sentences showing how you'd like to use the word?  (Please ping me when you do, so I can check my answer and change my vote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**professional**

To me, this would mean that the résumé is everything it should be, in every respect (content and appearance).  Such as the resume of a consummate professional.

Merriam-Webster:

> c(1): characterized by or conforming to the technical or ethical standards of a profession

Answer (score 0):

They have résumés with a lot more *[prestige](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prestige)*. Or as an adjective:

> Though they had high-level positions or were building up prestigious resumes, they chose to leave major corporations and launch their own startups. — [The big move: Leaving that corporate job for a startup](https://www.wework.com/ideas/professional-development/the-big-move-leaving-that-corporate-job-for-a-startup)